# Passing variable to function without a parameter

Tags: php, function

I have the following function that I got from a calendar class. Although I can't figure out how to pass the `$content` variable to it, since it's not a parameter. Anyone know how to set the `$content` variable for this so that the function will read it and know it's set?

```
private function day($day){
        if((bool) $day){
            $class   = $this->_class_defintions['working_day'];
            $content = isset($this->_day_data[($day)]) ? $this->_day_data[($day)] : '';
            $day_num = '<div class="'. $this->_class_defintions['day_number'] .'">'. $day .'</div>';

            /**
             * if there is content, set the class to whatever is content_day
             */
            if($content !== ''){
                $class = $this->_class_defintions['content_day'];
            }
        }else{
            $class   = $this->_class_defintions['blank_day'];
            $content = '';
            $day_num = '';
        }

        return '
            <td class="'. $class. '">
                <div class="calendar_day_container">
                    '. $day_num . $content .'
                </div>
            </td>
        ';
    }
```

Looking through the class this is the function that should set the `$content` but it doesn't work.

```
 /**
     * sets the data for a given day
     *
     * @param integer $day -- the zero key of the day to be modified
     * @param mixed $content -- the content for that day
     * @param boolean $append -- this will say to overwrite the day or not with the data. Defaults to true
     * @access public
     * @return return type
     */
    public function setDayData($day, $content, $append = true){
        $current_content       = isset($this->_day_data[$day]) ? $this->_day_data[$day] : '';
        $this->_day_data[$day] = $append ? $current_content . $content : $content;

        return $this;
    }
```

I tried to set the content but running the following:

```
 $test = "This is a test";
            $this->setDayData($list_day,$test, true);
```

Comment: You can add an argument to the `day()` function and give it a default value: `private function day($day, $myArg = NULL){//code}` then check the value of `$myArg` inside the function

Comment: Something weird, but i just tried for testing to set the following $this->setDayData(15,$test, true); and that works but when i try to set it like this it doesn't work, $this->setDayData($list_day,$test, true);  $list_day is just a variable in a loop that goes from 1 to 31

Answer (score 0):

You can add an argument to the `day()` function and give it a default value, 
then check the value of `$myArg` inside the function:

```
private function day($day, $myArg = NULL){
    if($myArg !== NULL) {
        //do something
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

What your mysterious `setDayData` function does is simply associate contents with a given day.

If you set `append` to `false`, the contents will overwrite any previous contents. If you set it to `true`, it will add the new content to the previous one.

It means that if you call `setDayData` only once for any given day, the result will be exactly the same regardless of the `append` parameter.

There is no such thing as a `content` member in your class, because the class handles multiple days.
Instead, each content is dispatched inside the `_day_data` array, indexed by day.

So to retrieve it, you must look inside this array for a given day, which is exactly what the line `$content = isset($this->_day_data[($day)]) ? $this->_day_data[($day)] : '';` does, although the braces around `$day` are quite unnecessary.

What your mysterious code does in regard to class is :

- set it to `blank day` if `$day`=0 (I wonder why you would want to cast it to bool, btw)
- set it to `working day` if `$day`!=0 and there is no content defined for that day
- set it to `content day` if $day!=0 and there is content defined for that day

I suppose `blank` is used as a filler for days outside the current month, `working` for days where no content (agenda notes I suppose) has been defined, and `content` for days where there are notes to display.

As far as I can tell, the `setDayData` method works perfectly.
However, it is part of a class, so you won't get anything if you don't create an instance of the class, call `setDayData` a few times ***before*** calling your `day($day)` method ***and*** make sure you don't invoke other methods of the mysterious class that would mess up the contents.

To see what is going on, a few calls to `var_dump` should show you what state your object is in after you called `setDayData` and before you call `day()`.

My bet is, you're not working on the same object instance or you invoked another class method that messed up the contents.